# Don't understand why do I get a permission denied error

Tags: shell, chmod

I have a file hello.c with "hello world" program in C. I also done the following on the shell (UNIX):

```
$ ls > 1
$ chmod 0 1
$ cc -o hello hello.c
$ chmod 400 hello
$ ./hello > 1
```

And I got permission denied on 1.

Why I didn't get the permission denied error on hello?

Comment: Yes, but the chmod with 400 on hello blocks its permission of execution. So what happen first? hello run on the permission for 1?

Comment: What does the evidence suggest?

Comment: Debugging step: what do you think `chmod 0 1` does? What do you think `chmod 400 hello` does?

Comment: The evidence of course suggests the permission for 1, but if have a command, how can I know what will happen first?

Comment: Because if the hello program runs first, I should get the permission denied error on hello. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but why does it matter?

Comment: Of course it doesn't matter for me. The question was originally taken from an exam in my university, and I'm solving these exams to understand how the things works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you ask a shell to perform an output redirection for a command, the file to write to is opened by the shell, *before* invoking the command.

Your shell will:

1. open `1` for writing
2. "wire" `./hello` `stdout` to `1`
3. run `./hello`

`1` has permissions `0o000`, so the first operation will fail.